# How to create dynamic product image in Magento 2 on creating Product?

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image

I have created a module to create simple product in Magento 2.

I want to create dynamic image for product with product name and save that image as product image.

How would i do that ?
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Dynamic image means? Can you please explain bit more this sentence?

Comment: Suppose if my product name in XYZ so i want to create an image with XYZ using a php library which is not that difficult but how to save that image and select that as an product image? @MayurSisodiya

Comment: Still confusing, anyway you can not create an image you can rename it and save it please follow below link: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html

Also, you can configure default image from back-end store configuration and can assign them while saving products.

Comment: are you using gdlibrary?

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion.@Pramod
Done that by using gdlibrary.